# Windows Universal App: Storyboard have strange behaviour with Dependency Props

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

Hi I have port my class to Universal App (windows phone 8.1 in my case)

here's a simple helper class for animation, and seems works well (read below)

```
public class FastEaseAnimation
{
    Storyboard _animationStoryboard = new Storyboard();
    DoubleAnimation _animation;
    Func<double> _from;
    Func<double> _to;

    public FastEaseAnimation(DependencyObject target, string targetPropertyName, Func<double> from, Func<double> to, TimeSpan duration,EasingMode easingMode=EasingMode.EaseIn)
    {
        _from = from; _to = to;
        _animation = new DoubleAnimation
        {
            Duration = duration,
            From =  _from(),
            To = _to(),
            EasingFunction = new CubicEase { EasingMode = easingMode }

        };


        Storyboard.SetTarget(_animation, target);


        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(_animation, targetPropertyName);

        _animationStoryboard.Children.Add(_animation);

    }

    public void Begin() {

        _animation.From = _from();
        _animation.To = _to();
        _animationStoryboard.Begin();
    }



    public Task<bool> BeginAsync() {

        TaskCompletionSource<bool> beginAnim = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();    

         _animation.From = _from();
         _animation.To = _to();

        _animationStoryboard.Completed += (snd,arg) => {
            beginAnim.SetResult(true);
        };
        _animationStoryboard.Begin();

        return beginAnim.Task;
    }



} }
```

then I have tested on a simple windows phone app,

a blue box to fading out on screen

here's main windows (code behind)

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {


        public double TestDp
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(TestDpProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TestDpProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for TestDp.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TestDpProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("TestDp", typeof(double), typeof(MainPage), new PropertyMetadata(1.0,onTestDpChange));

        private static void onTestDpChange(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var k = 0; //this never Happens
        }


        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;

            this.Loaded+=MainPage_Loaded;

            DataContext = this;



        }

        async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


            FastEaseAnimation anim =
                new FastEaseAnimation(MyAnimatedRectangle,
                    "Opacity",
                    () => { return 1.0; },
                    () => { return 0.0; },
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

            await anim.BeginAsync();


            FastEaseAnimation anim2 =
                new FastEaseAnimation(this,
                    "TestDp",
                    () => { return 1.0; },
                    () => { return 0.0; },
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            await anim2.BeginAsync();




        }


    }
```

Well if you look at anim (FastEasyAnimation) all works well, MyAnimatedRectangle is a blue plain rectangle, and fade out as aspected, but when I use a Dependencyproperty of "this" class Nothing happens

have an Idea why???
any solution?
thanks

Comment: [Set the animation's `EnableDependentAnimation` property to True.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685379/animate-dependency-properties)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 8 - Animating custom property in code-behind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890627/windows-8-animating-custom-property-in-code-behind)

Comment: great it works why don't put the answer ? thanks again